# Eclipse RCP/ Plug-in Question

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I have an RCP application (referred to as RCP-APP).  I have created a new plug-in (referred to as plug-in A) that wraps a media player api (.jar file) and a folder of C libraries (dlls) that the media player api accesses via JNA.  I then created another plugin (referred to as plug-in B) that contains a media player application that depends on Plug-in A.

When plug-in B is activated I get the following error messages informing me that Plug-in B cannot find the media player .dlls it is looking for:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2009-06-22 10:05:22.475
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
!STACK 0
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libvlc': The specified module could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:114)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:157)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:123)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:260)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:246)
    at org.videolan.jvlc.internal.LibVlc.(LibVlc.java:41)
    at org.videolan.jvlc.JVLC.(JVLC.java:45)
    at com.bah.gs.arts.jekyll.plugins.videolog.VideoLogDisplay.displayStream(VideoLogDisplay.java:32)
    at com.bah.gs.arts.jekyll.core.extensionpoints.DisplayStreamFactory.getDisplayStreams(DisplayStreamFactory.java:57)
    at com.bah.gs.arts.jekyll.core.views.medialist.MediaListView$1.doubleClick(MediaListView.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:880)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1419)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1173)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1003)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3823)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3422)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2384)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2348)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2200)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.bah.gs.arts.jekyll.core.Application.start(Application.java:20)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)
```

**How do I inform Plug-in B (or the RCP-APP) that the .dlls are in a specific folder in Plug-in A**?

It appears that the api expects to find the .dlls via it's environment PATH variable.

**How can I essentially communicate "plug-in A/Folder-Name"**?

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

To get access to the .DLL files in plugin-a/folder you need access to the `Bundle` instance of plug-in A. One way is to implement an `Activator` for plug-in A which extends at least the class `Plugin` ("`PluginA`").

The call `PluginA.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("folder/some.dll")` will return an URL to the .DLL file.

IMHO it is better to put all code that directly accesses the .DLL files into plug-in A. This way you don't need to expose the internal file structure of your plug-in to its users.

Comment: "IMHO it is better to put all code that directly accesses the .DLL files into plug-in A. This way you don't need to expose the internal file structure of your plug-in to its users."

That's true.  But that infers every plug-in I create that uses the media player api will have a copy of the dlls and the .jar file.  This is what I was trying to avoid by placing the .jar file and .dlls in it's own plug-in.

Comment: Anyway.....  I api is attempting to find the .dlls via the PAT variable.  I was mistaken about being able to pass the location as a parameter to the api.

Comment: So you have different plug-ins that call functionality from the .DLLs? You can implement a facade for that functionality in "plug-in A" that handles the access to the .DLLs and manages the PATH variable. So you don't have to do all this fiddling in the other plug-ins.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to look at plugin fragments; this provides a mechanism to keep the public facing Java API apart from the (platform specific) dll/so files.

The packaging of SWT would be a good place to start looking at this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a "binaries" plugin, put the dll in a subfolder bin/ of it, then make sure in the manifest 
* you add an activator + singleton property.
* you check bin/ in the "Build", "Runtime Build" section

In the feature that includes your binaries plug-in, make sure to check "Unpack the plugin archive after installation"

In the activator of your binaries plugin, add something like this :

```
public enum Tool {reach, ctl, ltl};
private static URI toolUri [] = new URI [3];

public static URI getProgramURI(Tool tool) throws IOException {
    if (toolUri[tool.ordinal()] == null) {
        String relativePath = "bin/its-"+ tool.toString() ;
        URL toolff = getDefault().getBundle().getResource(relativePath);
        if (toolff == null) {
            log.severe("unable to find an executable [" + tool + "] in path " + relativePath);
            Enumeration<URL> e = getDefault().getBundle().findEntries("bin/", "*", true);
            log.fine("Lising URL available in bin/");
            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                log.finer(e.nextElement().toString());
            }
            throw new IOException("unable to find the tool binary");
        }
        URL tmpURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(toolff);

        // use of the multi-argument constructor for URI in order to escape appropriately illegal characters
        URI uri;
        try {
            uri = new URI(tmpURL.getProtocol(), tmpURL.getPath(), null);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IOException("Could not create a URI to access the binary tool :", e);
        }
        toolUri[tool.ordinal()] = uri;
        log.fine("Location of the binary : " + toolUri);

        File crocExec = new File(uri);
        if (!crocExec.setExecutable(true)) {
            log.severe("unable to make the command-line tool executable [" + toolUri + "]");
            throw new IOException("unable to make the command-line tool executable");
        }       

    }
    return toolUri[tool.ordinal()];
}
```

I copy pasted from some code of mine, so sorry it doesn't perfectly match your DLL example, I was getting executable paths from a restricted list (see enum Tool). The last step (setting the +x flag on the file) is probably useless in your case. On the other hand you get some exception handling code and a cache for free :) And its tested pretty thoroughly.

It does the job you are trying to do, pass the url to the binary to the downstream plugin.

Comment: Once you have the information, you can programmatically update the environment's PATH to include this folder. With "unzip" checked and the URI used in my code you get stuff that is compatible with plain java.io.File api.